# Volly: Implemetation of methods by following DRY principle

Tags: android, android-volley, dry

I need to call an api to get a json data using android volly. I have a method implemented inside class A to call the get request as shown

```
class A{
public static String getList(Context context,String url)
{
    final String[] result = new String[1];

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.e("response",response.toString());
                    result[0] =response.toString();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("responseerror",error.toString());
            result[0] =error.toString();
        }
    });

    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(req);


    return result[0];
}
}
```

Inside class B i am accesing this method

```
class B {
String responce= A.getList(activity,url);
}
```

Here i can pass the context and url to get json data. But the problem  is getList() method ruturs result even before it gets any response from the server. The app have more than one class which needs to call get request. If i will use this code snippet inside every such class then it will be against DRY principle. So what is the proper procudure to follow in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `interface` like below.

```
class A {
  private final WeakReference<ResponseListener> responseListenerWeakRef;

  public A(ResponseListener responseListener) {
    responseListenerWeakRef = new WeakReference<ResponseListener>(responseListener);
  }

  public String getList(Context context, String url) {
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url, 
      new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
          Log.e("response",response.toString());
          if (responseListener!=null && responseListener.get()!=null) {
            responseListener.get().onResponse(response.toString());
          }
        }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          Log.e("responseerror",error.toString());
          if (responseListener!=null && responseListener.get()!=null) {
            responseListener.get().onResponse(error.toString());
          }
        }
      }
    );
    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(req);
  }

  public interface ResponseListener {
    void onResponse(String response);
  }
}

class B implements A.ResponseListener {
  private void makeApiCall() {
    new A(this).getList(activity, url);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResponse(String response) {
    // Do something with the response.
  }
}
```